# Angular Http Post not working. Error: Unsupported Media Type

Tags: angular, http, post, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following method on an web api asp.net core app

Api post method:

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody] List<ValuesToPost> values)
{
  return values.Count.ToString();

}
```

It Works with Postman: POST 
JSON(application/json)
Body -> raw:

```
[{
    Value: "asd",
    Column:2,
    Row:1,
    IsPostBack: true
},
{
    Value: "assddfs",
    Column:2,
    Row:1,
    IsPostBack: true
}]
```

And on my Angular app :

ComponentOne

```
    sendDataToTheServerByPost(arrayOfObjects: any) {

      this.dataService.postData(arrayOfObjects).subscribe(event => {
        console.log("post");

      });

  }
```

DataService.ts

```
     public postData(body: any): Observable<any> {

        let bodyToSend = JSON.stringify(body);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

        return this.http.post(this.DataUrl,  bodyToSend, { headers: headers }).map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json().data;
        }).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I'm receiving the following error on the Chrome console:

```
  Error
  zone.js:2622 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/api/values 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

What I'm I missing, In Postman the call to the API post method works, but not from angular app. All running on same Dev computer. CORS problem I don't think so because Get Method works fine. Or Am I wrong? Sugestions?

Comment: what media type is your server api method returning?  and does your api accept OPTIONS requests?  looks like angular is feeling out the endpoint before posting

Comment: your server should accept OPTIONS method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

At the end, nothing was wrong with Angular. It was a CORS problem. Apparently, there are different ways of dealing with this, I was doing it on web.config as the older versions of Web API. After investigating and testing, I've found a well-explained way [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas#Checkthatitworks) on Rick Strahl's Web Log. The first comment on the Post makes reference to GitHub repo that has a well configured ASpNetCore App with Angular. In case others having the same Issue

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue posting the following object

```
let song = {
  title : this.title.value,
  url: this.url.value,
  artist: this.artist.value
};

this.service.create(song)
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

I got it working by explicitly typecasting each element of the object as:

```
let song = {
  title : this.title.value as string,
  url: this.url.value as string,
  artist: this.artist.value as string
};

this.service.create(song)
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```